# Installing MySQLi shows it will disable MySQL will it affect my current code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, installation

I am trying to install mysqli extension on my server(CENTOS) using WHM Easy Apache 3.
I am selecting mysqli from Exhaustive Options List.
When I select mysqli extension it shows message that this action will disable current mysql extension.

Now, my problem is whether this action will affect my current websites code which is already using mysql extension. I have multiple websites on this server all are built using mysql extension.

I need mysqli for my new website of opencart.

Please help me to understand this warning also let me know if mysql is disabled then can I enable it again and how? so that I can use both mysql & mysqli extensions and my old work will not be affected by this change.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was in a bit of a hurry, so I took risk to build apache and php using easyapache3 and guess what.... my current code with mysql is not affected at all and both mysql and mysqli extensions are working fine, though I will not recommend to use mysql further to any one, but now I have a time to upgrade my old sites to mysqli and also I am able to use mysqli immediately for my new projects.

Note : when you build apache and php your php.ini might be rewritten by new default settings, so if you have any custom settings in php.ini remember to backup it first and then build apache.

Thanks a lot...